# Expand rows to columns in presto

Tags: presto

Any way to expand rows to columns in presto efficiently?

[image: Problem]

I've tried to filter the raw dataset with 'where team = 1' and 'where  team = 2' separately, to get the dataset1 and dataset 2 correspondingly first, and then join the two datasets on income_level. However it is inconvenient when income_level has too many different values. Is there any efficient way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2):

Prestodb offers a `map_agg` function that can help to convert your long data to the wide format you are looking for. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically created the column names, but this approach should be far more efficient (and less typing :) ) than joining on each team.

```
WITH raw_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS team, 'a' AS income_level, 1 AS time, 11 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 1 AS team, 'b' AS income_level, 2 AS time, 12 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 1 AS team, 'c' AS income_level, 3 AS time, 13 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS team, 'a' AS income_level, 4 AS time, 14 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS team, 'b' AS income_level, 5 AS time, 15 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS team, 'c' AS income_level, 6 AS time, 16 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS team, 'a' AS income_level, 7 AS time, 17 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS team, 'b' AS income_level, 8 AS time, 18 AS ord
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS team, 'c' AS income_level, 9 AS time, 19 AS ord
)

SELECT
  income_level,
  team_time[1] AS time_1,
  team_ord[1] AS ord_1,
  team_time[2] AS time_2,
  team_ord[2] AS ord_2,
  team_time[3] AS time_3,
  team_ord[3] AS ord_3
FROM (
  SELECT
    income_level,
    map_agg(team, time) AS team_time,
    map_agg(team, ord) AS team_ord
  FROM raw_data
  GROUP BY income_level
);
```

Output:

```
| income_level | time_1 | ord_1 | time_2 | ord_2 | time_3 | ord_3 |
|--------------|--------|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|
| a            | 1      | 11    | 4      | 14    | 7      | 17    |
| b            | 2      | 12    | 5      | 15    | 8      | 18    |
| c            | 3      | 13    | 6      | 16    | 9      | 19    |
```

[This site](https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/sql-tips#presto) provides another example of how this can be done.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. In fact, the raw dataset I posted above is a simple version. In the full dataset,  `income_level`  is represented on all teams, however, there are  8 teams with values [0,1,2,10,11,12,21,22]. And the solution I came up with is to create the first table with `where team = 0` , then join the second table created with  `where team = 1` , on `income_level`.  Repeat these steps until `team = 22`. And this way seems to be less efficient.

Comment: @GuoyingZheng thanks for the clarification. I updated my solution to utilize the `map_agg` function, which does a better job of pivoting the data when there are more than two teams.